# running solr instance inside docker

Tags: shell, solr, docker

I am trying to write a shell script to run solr inside a docker container. I have written the following script but it is not working. But when I give the same command step by step in terminal it works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
#pull solr image
docker pull makuk66/docker-solr

#run solr on a single server
SOLR_CONTAINER=$(docker run -d -p 8983:8983 -t makuk66/docker-solr)

#create solr core
docker exec -it --user=solr $SOLR_CONTAINER bin/solr create_core -c gettingstarted

#load data using bin/post from example directory in solr installation directory
docker exec -it --user=solr $SOLR_CONTAINER bin/post -c gettingstarted example/films/films.json
```

Comment: Instead of `bin/solr` specify absolute path and see if it works. Same for `bin/post`

Comment: Do you see any error during build? any logs files?

Comment: @Dharmit I tried with absolute path but its not working.

Comment: @Viswesn its showing "Failed to determine the port of a local Solr instance, cannot create gettingstarted!"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the creator of the solr docker isn't using volumes and such so makes persistence/configuration harder. The error you're getting is the error you get when solr isn't running.

The create_core command just posts to solr at localhost.

Different/better way is to create the core as part of the build. Create a Dockerfile and extend.

My Dockerfile that creates a core:

```
FROM makuk66/docker-solr
WORKDIR /opt/solr/server/solr/
ADD . /opt/solr/server/solr/
USER root
RUN chown -R solr /opt/solr/server/solr
USER solr
```

That ADD . is adding a directory (my core) which contains an empty core.properties and another director (conf) which contains the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml

Comment: Do you have an example at all?